# Lua. Attempt to index global "a" (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm getting the following error:

> Attempt to index global "a" (a nil value)

```
   local gfx = love.graphics
    return{
        new = function( Image, Animation, Time)        
        return{
        current_frame = 1,
        current_anim = 1,
        image = Image,
        a = Animation,
        play = false,
        time = Time or 0,2,
        counter = 0,
    
        update = function(dt)
        if play then
                    counter = counter + dt
                    if counter >= time then
                        counter = 0
                        current_frame = current_frame + 1
                    end
    
                    if current_frame > #a[current_anim] then
                        current_frame = 1
                    end
                else
    
                end
        end,
    
        play = function()
        play = true
        end,
    
        stop = function()
        play = false    
        end,
    
        set_animation = function(anim)
        if anim > #a then error("there is no animation ", anim) return end
        current_anim = anim
    
        end,
    
        draw = function(data)
        gfx.draw(image, a[current_anim][current_frame], data[1], data[2])
        end
    
        }
        end
    }
```

it seems to me, that I do give "a" a value - a table, containing a set of images, which I assign through second parameter.

```
    -----
    
    local quad = love.graphics.newQuad
    local anim_data = {
      quad(0,0, 32, 48, 192, 256),
      quad(32,0, 32, 48, 192, 256),
      quad(64,0, 32, 48, 192, 256),
      quad(96,0, 32, 48, 192, 256),
      quad(129,0, 32, 48, 192, 256),
      quad(162,0, 32, 48, 192, 256)
    
    }
    local image = love.graphics.newImage("images/player_animation.png")
    image:setFilter("nearest","nearest")
```

Here I supposedly give 'a' a value

```
    animation = require("animations"):new(
            image,
    
            {
              { -- idle
                anim_data[1]
              },
              { -- walk
                anim_data[2],
                anim_data[3],
                anim_data[4],
                anim_data[5],
                anim_data[6]
              },
            },
            
            0.2
          )
    
    animation.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `a` you are looking for is part of the table you are returning from the `new` function. It is not visible from the scope of those functions.

The *easiest* solution is to move the values you've placed in the table up in the scope of the `new` function, *encapsulating* them. However, this removes them from the table, so they won't be visible outside of the `new`, `.play`, `.pause`, `.draw`, `.update`, or `.set_animation` functions.

A better solution is to employ a more typical OOP solution, so I would suggest reading chapter 16 of Programming in Lua: [Object-oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html). Once you've read that chapter, go read every other just to be safe (particularly 5, 6, and 11).

```
local gfx = love.graphics

return {
    new = function (Image, Animation, Time)        
        local current_frame = 1
        local current_anim = 1
        local image = Image
        local a = Animation
        local play = false
        local time = Time or 0,2
        local counter = 0

        return {
            update = function (dt)
                if play then
                    counter = counter + dt
                    if counter >= time then
                        counter = 0
                        current_frame = current_frame + 1
                    end

                    if current_frame > #a[current_anim] then
                        current_frame = 1
                    end
                end
            end,

            play = function ()
                play = true
            end,

            stop = function ()
                play = false
            end,

            set_animation = function (anim)
                if anim > #a then
                    error("there is no animation ", anim)
                    return
                end

                current_anim = anim

            end,

            draw = function (data)
                gfx.draw(image, a[current_anim][current_frame], data[1], data[2])
            end
        }
    end
}
```